# TFS Permissions Audit

Tags: tfs

I have a requirement from our company auditors to be able to prove who can alter code in our source repository. Is there a method of producing a report detailing permissions?

Ideally the report would show all permissions but at least it needs to show check-in permissions. Ideally the report would be standard functionality as this tends to lead to less questioning from the auditors, but if not possible then custom reports/queries would be manageable.

We're using TFS 2018 on premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check extension [TFS Permission Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KonstantinErman.TFSPermissionVisualizer), which displays TFS security groups and permissions in a form of a graph.

Also, you could refer to the solution [Extracting effective permissions](https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/Extracting-effective-permissions-from-TFS) from TFS on GitHub. This practical guidance and sample code is based on extensive research to address two of the commonly heard requests on Team Foundation Server security:

- Report on the effective permissions of a TFS user/group.
- Report on security auditing for TFS.

Comment: The solution only provides a report for a specific user, however with some fairly simple modifications that should achieve exactly what I'm after. Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

Clone and build [TFS Team Project Manager](https://github.com/jelledruyts/TfsTeamProjectManager).

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of TFS Team Project Manager Security Tab]

See also: https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/Extracting-effective-permissions-from-TFS/blob/master/Doc/Extracting%20effective%20permissions%20whitepaper.md